# Restore last save on Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, restore

I opened Notepad++ and add some notes on already opened **hosts** file and saved it. Then I noticed my Windows **hosts** file is missing a line.

Is there any way to undo to before the last save (ctrl + z didn't work)?

Answer (score 0):

If you saved overtop already, and ctrl-Z doesn't work, then Notepad++ can do nothing to undo your actions.

Try to use Windows' "[Previous Versions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/previous-versions-files-faq#1TC=windows-7)" to get an older copy of that file.  Otherwise, restore your file from a known-good backup.